# Complex issue with Polymorphism in C#

Tags: polymorphism

[image: Class Diagram]

I’m building an application that allows the manufacturer to enter the specification of the car. Now, let’s say that I enter the name of the car (stored in Car table), *type of the engine (stored in the table specified for that type of the engine)

***Note:** each engine must be stored in a separate table since the structure of engine tables is different. For instance, if the engine of the car is 4 Cyl, it must be stored in 4 Cyl table.

In the application, there is a feature that allows the manufacturer to go back and modify/view the car specification. In this feature, when he/she clicks “view car”, the 4 Cyl car shows up with its own specification, 6 Cyl car with its own specification, and so on. Now, the issue is when I retrieve the data, how can I assign the correct engine object to each car.

Can I use any design pattern to solve this issue?

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) Please put all essential information in your posts ([questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)). Links are welcome for detail and reference, but they may go stale. How to *table*s enter the picture? Sounds *database* to me. In Object-Oriented Modelling, *classes* and specialisations are common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is among those very common ones that require to use Abstract Factory Design Pattern to solve them. 
The abstract factory pattern offers an interface to encapsulate several factories that have a shared theme or you can say that abstract factory is a super factory working as an abstraction of other factories.
The following code may help solving your problem. You can modify the code to work properly for your application.
Now, you need to build your concrete classes: Car, 4Cyl, 6Cyl, and 8Cyl classes. After that, you need to build a factory class for each engine + the car itself:

- Factory for 4Cyl + Car
- Factory for 6Cyl + Car
- Factory for 8Cyl + Car, and so on if you have more types of engine.

  ```
  public class Car
  {
      private int _id;

      public Car(int id)
      {
          _id = id;
      }

      public Car retrieveCar()
      {
          return new Car(_id);
      }
  }
  ```

the following is an interface for the engines:

```
public interface IEngine
{
    IEngine retrieveEngine();
}
```

Then, we need to write concrete class for each engine type:

```
public class FourCyl : IEngine
{
    private int _id = 0;

    public FourCyl(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
    public IEngine retrieveEngine()
    {
        return new FourCyl(_id);
    }
}

public class SixCyl : IEngine
{
    private int _id = 0;

    public SixCyl(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public IEngine retrieveEngine()
    {
        return new SixCyl(_id);
    }
}

public class EightCyl : IEngine
{
    private int _id =0;

    public EightCyl(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
    public IEngine retrieveEngine()
    {
        return new EightCyl(_id);
    }
}
```

**Note:** you can replace the code of creating new object such as "*return new EightCyl(_id)*" by writing your own code that retrieves data from your database.

Now, we need to write the code for the abstract factory:

```
interface ICarFactory
{
    Car car();
    IEngine engine();
}
```

Then, we need to list or write all factories classes:

```
class FourCylCarFactory : ICarFactory
{
    private int _carId;
    private int _engineId;

    public FourCylCarFactory(int carID, int engineID)
    {
        _carId = carID;
        _engineId = engineID;
    }

    public Car car()
    {
        Car carObject = new Car(_carId);
        return carObject.retrieveCar();
    }

    public IEngine engine()
    {
        FourCyl engineObject = new FourCyl(_engineId);
        return engineObject.retrieveEngine();
    }
}

class SixCylCarFactory : ICarFactory
{
    private int _carId;
    private int _engineId;

    public SixCylCarFactory(int carID, int engineID)
    {
        _carId = carID;
        _engineId = engineID;
    }

    public Car car()
    {
        Car carObject = new Car(_carId);
        return carObject.retrieveCar();
    }

    public IEngine engine()
    {
        SixCyl engineObject = new SixCyl(_engineId);
        return engineObject.retrieveEngine();
    }

}

class EightCylCarFactory : ICarFactory
{
    private int _carId;
    private int _engineId;

    public EightCylCarFactory(int carID, int engineID)
    {
        _carId = carID;
        _engineId = engineID;
    }

    public Car car()
    {
        Car carObject = new Car(_carId);
        return carObject.retrieveCar();
    }

    public IEngine engine()
    {
        EightCyl engineObject = new EightCyl(_engineId);
        return engineObject.retrieveEngine();
    }
}
```

Finally, after creating the factories, you can start using them by creating your cars such as the following code:

```
class CarSystem
{
    public void createCar(int carID, int engineID)
    {
        ICarFactory carFactory = new EightCylCarFactory(carID, engineID);

        Car car = carFactory.car();
        IEngine engine = carFactory.engine();
    }
}
```

In this way, the polymorphism is applied in a good manner, and you can create new factory for each new engine type will appear in the future in order to easily keep the commitment to many OO principles such as OCP principle (Open/Closed Principle) open to extend/add and close to change.